# PHP Notice: Undefined index: idCarpeta in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Gestor_Documental\\Controlador\\Documentos\\Eliminar Carpetas.php on line 5

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

Tengo el siguiente código para eliminar filas en la tabla y en la base de datos `carpetas` pero me muestra

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: idCarpeta in C:\xampp\htdocs\Gestor_Documental\Controlador\Documentos\Eliminar Carpetas.php on line 5

y esta corresponde a `echo $Carpetas->EliminarCarpeta($_POST['idCarpeta']);`

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../../Modelo/Carpetas.php';
$Carpetas = new Carpetas();
echo $Carpetas->EliminarCarpeta($_POST['idCarpeta']);
```

Aquí esta la clase `EliminarCarpetas`

```
  public function EliminarCarpeta($idCarpeta) {
        $Conexion = Conectar::Conexion();
        $sql = "DELETE FROM carpetas WHERE id_carpeta = ?";
        $query = $Conexion->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('i', $idCarpeta);
        $respuesta = $query->execute();
        return $respuesta;
    }
```

Aquí esta la función en `js EliminarCarpeta`

```
function EliminarCarpeta(idCarpeta) {
    idCarpeta = parseInt(idCarpeta);
    if (idCarpeta < 1) {
        swal("No tienes id de documento");
        return false;
    } else {
        //**********************************
        swal({
            title: "Estas seguro de eliminar esta carpeta?",
            text: "Una vez eliminada, no podra recuperarse!",
            icon: "warning",
            buttons: true,
            dangerMode: true,
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
            if (willDelete) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    date: "idCarpeta=" + idCarpeta,
                    url:"../../Controlador/Documentos/Eliminar Carpetas.php",         
                    success: function(respuesta) {
                        respuesta = respuesta.trim();
                        if (respuesta == 1) {
                            swal("Eliminado con exito!", {
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                        } else {
                            swal(":(", "Fallo al eliminar!", "error");
                        }
                    }
                        });
            } 
        });
        //**********************************
    }
}
```

Y aquí la pagina donde carga la tabla que por mostrar este error no elimina la fila mediante el `onclick="EliminarCarpeta('<?php echo $idCarpeta ?>')"`

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>Editor  de Documentos</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="../Imagenes/Astroproyect3.png" type="image/png">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/Mis_Estilos.css">
     </head>
    <body>
         <header class="Encabezado">
             <img class="Astroproyect2" src="../Imagenes/Astroproyect2.png" alt="Astroproyect2"/>
        </header>
        <main class="main">
            <div class="barra_desplegable">
                <button class="boton_desplegable">Usuario</button>
                <nav class="contenido_desplegable">
                    <a href="Perfil de Usuario.php">Perfil de Usuario</a>
                    <a href="../../Controlador/Usuario/Salir.php">Cerrar sesión</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="linea"></div>
            <form class="filter">
                 <label>Filtrar lista de archivos</label>
                 <input class="miboton" type="search" name="Buscar" id="Buscar" value="Buscar" />
                 <input class="image2" type="image" src="../Imagenes/confirmar.png" alt="confirmar" />
            </form>
            <?php
            require_once '../../Modelo/Conexion.php';
            $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
            $Conexion = new Conectar();
            $Conexion = $Conexion->Conexion();
            ?>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre de Archivo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT id_carpeta, nombre_carpeta FROM carpetas WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($Conexion, $sql);
                    while ($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $idCarpeta = $mostrar['id_carpeta'];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="../Imagenes/carpeta.png" alt="carpeta"/>
                            <?php echo $mostrar['nombre_carpeta'];?>
                            <input onclick="EliminarCarpeta('<?php echo $idCarpeta ?>')" type="image" src="../Imagenes/cerrar.png" alt="cerrar"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="table">
                <form>
                    <p class="filter">
                        <label>Agregar carpeta</label>
                        <input class="miboton" type="text" name="NombreCarpeta" id="NombreCarpeta" />
                        <input class="image2" type="image" src="../Imagenes/Agregar Carpeta.png" id="AgregarCarpeta" alt="mas" />
                    </p>
                </form>
                <div class="linea"></div>
                <form>
                    <p>
                        <label class="etiqueta">Departamento</label>
                        <input class="entrada2" type="text" name="Departamento" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label class="etiqueta">Descripcion</label> 
                        <textarea name="Descripcion" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>   
                    </p> 
                    <p class="barra2">
                        <input class="miboton2" type="file" name="Nuevo archivo"/>
                        <input class="image2" type="image" src="../Imagenes/mas.png" id="AgregarArchivo" alt="mas" />
                    </p> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="../../Libreria/Bootstrap4/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Libreria/Bootstrap4/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/Carpetas.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $('#AgregarCarpeta').click(function(){
                  AgregarCarpeta();
               }); 
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
    <?php
} else {
    header("location:../../Inicio de sesión.php");
}
```

Comment: Hola. Una duda: `<input onclick="EliminarCarpeta('<?php echo $idCarpeta ?>')" type="image" src="../Imagenes/cerrar.png" alt="cerrar"/>`. Esto te está imprimiendo el id de la carpeta? Me parece que no está haciendo el echo.

Answer (score 0):

Si usas `$.ajax()` para enviar los datos debes cambiar `date:` por `data:` (datos POST). Si el valor de `idCarpeta` posee caracteres especiales, es mejor codificar el valor usando `encodeURIComponent`.
Si usas el formato de datos `data1=value1&data2=value2` (*URL encoded*) debes explicitar  el formato de envio usando `contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`:

```
              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: "idCarpeta=" + encodeURIComponent(idCarpeta),
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                url:"../../Controlador/Documentos/Eliminar Carpetas.php",         
                success: function(respuesta) {
                    respuesta = respuesta.trim();
                    if (respuesta == 1) {
                        swal("Eliminado con exito!", {
                        icon: "success",
                    });
                    } else {
                        swal(":(", "Fallo al eliminar!", "error");
                    }
                }
              });
```

Como comentario adicional, es comun utilizar nombres de archivo sin espacios, por ejemplo usar `EliminarCarpetas.php` en reemplazo de `Eliminar Carpetas.php`). Puede producir problemas en [varios escenarios de uso](https://superuser.com/questions/29111/what-technical-reasons-exist-for-not-using-space-characters-in-file-names), por ejemplo en URLs y en linea de comandos.

Comment: Muchas gracias el error si estaba en el `date` al cambiarlo por `data`la función `EliminarCarpeta` la realizo correctamente.. : )